# Unable to change settings of Exchange accounts in Mail on macOS Catalina 10.15.2

Tags: macos, mail.app, catalina, accounts, exchange

I have a few accounts configured in Mail on macOS 10.15.2. I want to change these three settings:

- "*Download Attachements*" to `all`
- "*Delete spam*"<sup>(*)</sup> to `never`
- "*Delete permanently*"<sup>(*)</sup> to `never`

Now, this works fine for my iCloud account and all my IMAP accounts. Unfortunately this doesn't work for all three Exchange accounts.

I change the settings and after a few seconds they switch back to their previous values, like `after a month`.

Is this an issue in 10.15? On my previous system with 10.13 it worked fine.

---

<sub><sup>(*)</sup> My system is in German, so I don't know the actual translation. If somebody could update the wording, that would be great. Thanks.</sub>

Comment: All Exchange data is kept on the server so deleting and re-adding the account with the desired settings is worth trying. It is also possible that your Exchange admin has disallowed those options, meaning you **can't** change those settings.

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks for your feedback. We checked. There are no user adjustable settings in a company's Office 365 and a personal Outlook address for these three options unfortunately.